# How to simulate a SQL server database with Watir

Tags: c#, watir

I'm planning the tests for a new .NET MVC web app with SQL Server database.

The test app has its own test database. However, this database can be used by anyone (including end users) to try anything. So, the contents change frequently.

I want to know if it's possible to use Watir to (a) use an in-memory database, or (b) mock/stub a database.  The real code will react as if the false data came from the real test database. The real code will therefore populate the UI, send emails, export reports to Excel, etc.  Only the data will be false.

How the app will work:

- The application maintains several "lists".
- The home page contains a grid.
- The first row in the grid contains info about the first list: name, owner, date created, current status, type of list, etc.
- The second row contains info about the second list, and so on.

There are 8 types of list. Each type has slightly different functionality. So I need only about 8 rows of data.

If it makes things easier, I think it might not be necessary to save the data between one test and another. I can run the entire sequence of functionality in a single test, as follows:

- Open home page. Grid is empty.
- Add a list of type1.
- Save. Grid contains one list.
- Add people to the list, save, open list ("open" = make list public), add more people, close list.
- During all this time, the grid contains only one row, but will show different numbers of people, different statuses, date/time modified, etc.
- End the test. Close browser.
- Start new test for type2.
- Grid is empty again.
- Repeat for 8 types of list.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Watir only drives browsers, it has no functionality for simulating databases. You will need a different library for simulating the database (if it is at all possible).

Comment: I got the idea from @alisterscott: [link]http://watirmelon.com/2013/12/    `#7 Fake back-end dependencies for quicker UI testing.` For a beginner like me @alisterscott = Watir. I checked the link again just now. The article was actually for Agile. Sorry for wasting people's time.